# Initialize database in SQL Server Linux container using Powershell Core

Tags: sql-server, dockerfile, powershell-core

I'm running SQL Server in a Linux container. When the container starts, I'd like some initialization and create a database using Powershell Core.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

ENV ACCEPT_EULA="Y" `
  DATA_PATH="./data" `
  sa_password="MyP@ssw0rd"

VOLUME ${DATA_PATH}
WORKDIR ./init

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y powershell

COPY SomeFolder/Initialize-Database.ps1 .
CMD pwsh ./Initialize-Database.ps1 -sa_password $env:sa_password -data_path $env:DATA_PATH -Verbose
```

In the Powershell script I'm installing the SQLServer module in order to perform SQL queries.

```
Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module SQLServer

if ($sa_password -ne "_") {
    Write-Verbose 'Changing SA login credentials'
    $sqlcmd = "CREATE DATABASE my-db"
    Invoke-SqlCmd -Query $sqlcmd -ServerInstance "."
}
```

The `Invoke-SqlCmd` command fails with a connection error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
     | establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
     | found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
     | correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
     | connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not
     | open a connection to SQL Server)
```

How do I check if the SQL instance is started and if not, how can I start it?
When I start a container using this image and exec into the container, `Get-SqlInstance -ServerInstance "." -Credential Get-Credential` fails with the error 'Failed to connect to server'.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the sa password/enable the account this way? The images already expect an `SA_PASSWORD` environment variable which they use to set the sa password on initial container create. REF: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

Comment: Thanks, I will skip this part from my script. But the question still remains: if I want to create a database in the script, how do I address the SQL instance? Is it supposed to be started at this point or should I start the instance myself somehow?

Comment: The SQL Server service takes some time to start, loading, verifying (and potentially upgrading) the system and user database files before it opens its server socket(s) to accept client connections. Depending on the speed of the host and the amount of shared activity this could take 20-30 seconds or more. [mssql-node-docker-demo-app](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app) isn't a great example - because it's installing a Node app inside the SQL Server container itself - but it does show you how to wait for SQL Server to start up before executing your own database script(s).

Answer (score 0):

Found it. In the Dockerfile, I'm now calling the Powershell script after SQL has started:

```
CMD ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" \
    && pwsh ./Initialize-Database.ps1 -sa_password $SA_PASSWORD -data_path $DATA_PATH -Verbose
```

https://www.kenmuse.com/blog/devops-sql-server-dacpac-docker